# What are the possible ways to optimize the below postgreSQL code?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, greenplum

I have written this SQL query to fetch the data from greenplum datalake. The primary table has hardy 800,000ish rows which I am joining with other table. The below query is taking insane amount of time to give result. What might be the possible reason for the longer query time? How to resolve it?

```sql
select    
          a.pole,
          t.country_name,
          a.service_area,  
          a.park_name,

          t.turbine_platform_name,
          a.turbine_subtype,
          a.pad as "turbine_name",
          t.system_number as "turbine_id",
          a.customer,
          a.service_contract,   

          a.component,
          c.vendor_mfg as "component_manufacturer",

          a.case_number,
          a.description as "case_description",
          a.rmd_diagnosis as "case_rmd_diagnostic_description",
          a.priority as "case_priority",
          a.status as "case_status",
          a.actual_rootcause as "case_actual_rootcause",
          a.site_trends_feedback as "case_site_feedback",
          a.added as "date_case_added",
          a.start as "date_case_started",
          a.last_flagged as "date_case_flagged_by_algorithm_latest",
          a.communicated as "date_case_communicated_to_field",
          a.field_visible_date as "date_case_field_visbile_date",
          a.fixed as "date_anamoly_fixed",
          a.expected_clse as "date_expected_closure",
          a.request_closure_date as "date_case_request_closure",
          a.validation_date as "date_case_closure",
          a.production_related,
          a.estimated_value as "estimated_cost_avoidance",
          a.cms,
          a.anomaly_category,
          a.additional_information as "case_additional_information",
          a.model,
          a.full_model,
          a.sent_to_field as "case_sent_to_field"

      from app_pul.anomaly_stage a
 left join ge_cfg.turbine_detail t on a.scada_number = t.system_number and a.added > '2017-12-31'
 left join tbwgr_v.pmt_wmf_tur_component_master_t c on a.component = c.component_name
```

Comment: Did you look at the explain plan? What indexes do you have? How are the tables partitioned? Please update your question with at least some of this information

Comment: Things to consider when you have slow queries on Greenplum: A) are the tables correctly distributed? Please update your post with Skew information over the tables. B) Are the join keys the exact same datatype? If not, greenplum does not perform well. C) What optimizer are you using? D) That filter is on varchar column? E) Did you check for cartesian? F) Are all segments Up? There is a few information missing so we can help you properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is basically:

```
 select . . .
 from app_pul.anomaly_stage a left join
      ge_cfg.turbine_detail t 
      on a.scada_number = t.system_number and
         a.added > '2017-12-31' left join
         tbwgr_v.pmt_wmf_tur_component_master_t c
         on a.component = c.component_name
```

First, the condition on `a` is ignored, because it is the first table in the `left join` and is the `on` clause.  So, I assume you actually intend for it to filter, so write the query as:

```
 select . . .
 from app_pul.anomaly_stage a left join
      ge_cfg.turbine_detail t 
      on a.scada_number = t.system_number left join
      tbwgr_v.pmt_wmf_tur_component_master_t c
      on a.component = c.component_name
 where a.added > '2017-12-31'
```

That might help with performance.  Then in Postgres, you would want indexes on `turbine_detail(system_number)` and `pmt_wmf_tur_component_master_t(component_name)`.  It is doubtful that an index would help on the first table, because you are already selecting a large amount of data.

I'm not sure if indexes would be appropriate in Greenplum.

Comment: I would advise to very carefully consider if there is the need for indexes, due to greenplum's architecture (https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/570/admin_guide/ddl/ddl-index.html).

Comment: Indexes might help in Greenplum, the same way they help in PostgreSQL: if you select small amounts of data, out of a large table. In addition, Greenplum also supports Bitmap indexes for certain OLAP queries.

Answer (score -2):

1. Verify if the joins are using respective primary and foreign keys.
2. Try to execute the query removing one left join after the other, so you see the focus the problem.
3. Try using the plan execution.